# Using Robot framework for mobile not able to get inside Frame

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using Robot framework to test a website on mobile phone. Things look good until Purchase page. I successfully invoke Chrome browser on phone, do operation such as adding items to cart. However, the payment page has card details inside a frame.

Appium library with Robot framework does not have a switch to frame and I am not sure how to get past this since everything inside a frame there.

I have tried to write a external python as well however it did not work out well. Please let me know if there exists some way we can access frame using Appium library with Robot framework.

Did not work as card number was inside frame -

```
AppiumLibrary.Input Text   xpath=//*[@name='cardnumber']
```

Also, external file did not work-

```
seleniumlib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('AppiumLibrary')
    seleniumlib.switch_to.frame("")
```